# How to validate value from arrayName.push() method using .inlcude() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

/*

- how to validate the arrayName.push(Value) to registeredUsers Array using .include() method.
- lets say the value I get from push method is going to validate in .include method

*/

let registeredUsers = ['Power Ranger 1',
'Power Ranger 2',
'Power Ranger 3' ];

function register(){

```
        // Adding an Element to lastIndex
        let  registerNew = registeredUsers.push("Power Ranger 1")
        console.log(registeredUsers);

        // Accessing the Last Index
        let newUser = registeredUsers.length - 1;
        console.log(registeredUsers[newUser]);

        // Check if the user is Existing
        let isUserExist = registeredUsers.includes(registerNew); // if Exists return Fail

        if( isUserExist ) {  
                registeredUsers.pop();
                alert("Username already exists!");

        } 
        else {  
                alert("Welcome New User");  
        }
        console.log(registeredUsers);
        
    }register();
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this line `let register = registeredUsers.push("");`?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: `let isUserNotExist = !(registeredUsers.includes(register)); // if not return Thank you`

Comment: Why push an empty string into the array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the .includes() method returns a boolean, so if the question is:
How to know if an array has a particular value/element in it? (In this case, to see if the username is taken). Just check if it is false or true, if its true then its taken, false if not.

```
let isUserExist = registeredUsers.includes(register);
if (isUserExist) { 
// username is taken please choose another
} 
else 
{
    // continue to register
}
```